# insert two fields from another table and third field from vairable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert two fields from another table2 and third field from vairable

```
SET @id = 10;  
INSERT INTO table1 (id,name,email) SELECT name, email FROM table2  ;
```

How do that

Comment: ?Just include the variable in the select- I can't believe you didn't try that so did you have a problem?

Comment: like INSERT INTO table1 (id,name,email) SELECT @id,name, email FROM table2  ;

Comment: Your SQL is correct.. so what is your issue?

Comment: How is this related to PHP or PDO? You haven't shared any such code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [PHP PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you can also use [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) with a prepared statement:

```
<?php

$id = 10; 
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table1 (id,name,email) SELECT :id, name, email FROM table2'); 
$sth->bindParam('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();

?>
```